# Care of/for/about something or somebody

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between

> Care **of** something or somebody
>
> Care **for** something or somebody
>
> Care **about** something or somebody

It seems to me there's no the difference.

Comment: You should provide a sentence example, edit your question to do so.

Comment: I think this is a fine question.  Grammer in foreign languages is different.  Non-naive speakers get this kind of thing wrong a lot.

Answer (score 8):

To take care **of** something/someone is to be responsible for its/their maintenance and well-being.

> I take care of my car.

To care **for** something/someone is to appreciate it/them and encourage or help it/them.

> I care for my wife very much.

To care **about** something/someone is to be concerned about its/their condition.

> I care about government overreach.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've signed in this stack exchange only to upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The choice of preposition is generally governed by the context. 
Although you sometimes have a choice of suitable prepositions, some fit better than others in certain constructions:

For example:

> > Please take care of my dog while I'm away.
> >
> > I care for my elderly neighbour.
> >
> > I don't care about the loss of your phone.

When it comes to choosing a preposition, there are few rules. You basically have to learn about their use by reading and listening.