# Is the expression 'To have no care of someone's tender feelings' wrong?

Tags: grammar

I recently read a text wherein the female protagonist cried:

> 'You have no care of my tender feelings!'

The preposition **'of'** struck me as unusual. Is it wrong, or merely old fashioned?

I am aware of this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/122549/55131), which explains the familiar usage only and is therefore of little help.

Edit:

I know that we would normally use 'for', or 'about' and no 'have'. That is precisely what prompted my question. I am not asking for help with rephrasing this. I am asking whether or not this particular usage is wrong. If it is correct, I am very much interested in the implications of using 'of', as well as in any flavour (archaic, regional...).

Comment: It depends on the type of care you're talking about. If it's emotional, you care **for** someone or something. If it's custodial, you have care **of** something or someone.

Comment: Was it written in the 18th century?  *have no care of my feelings* would be highly unusual in contemporary AmE, to be sure.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No. it is from an other writer's unpublished draft, so I have not shared the surrounding paragraphs.

Comment: It is old fashioned. Today someone might say: "You don't care if you hurt my feelings."

Comment: Declining in usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+care+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2006&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20care%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I would prefer *about*. Also *to do* is better than *to have*, so: "You don't care *about* my tender feelings!"

Comment: @user3169 In fact, "about" could *only* be used if "care" were the verb (or "don't care" in the negative). As the sentence stands, the most obvious correction is *of* → *for*. As Robusto said, you could potentially "have care of X" which means to be its guardian, but that meaning is rare, and it would be surprising for it to apply to someone else's feelings. Whereas exclamations about having no care *for* someone else's feelings are common.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just old-fashioned and simply is just another preposition meaning possibly "for" or even "regarding".  I looked up "of" on freedictionary.com and definitions 15a and 15b state that "of" can mean "with reference to; about" or "in respect to", so "You have no care of my tender feelings" simply means the same as "You have no care about my tender feelings".

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence

> You have no care **of** my tender feelings!

is understandable and might possibly be

> You have no care **for** my tender feelings!

since the usual phrase is

> **feelings for**

to mean *affection*.

> Do you have feelings **for** him/her?
>   *Do you feel affection for him/her?*

Comment: I have some doubts about this. Compare the phrase "Take care of the child." From this example we see that "care of my tender feelings" refers to protection of those feelings from hurt. It means "You carelessly say things which hurt my feelings." Changing "of" to "for" alters the meaning slightly suggesting nourishing care rather than mere protection. But the expression "to have feelings for" refers to a completely different kind of feelings had by a different person.